# Is there an easy way to see what is consuming the most memory?

Tags: workflow, memory-management

**Is there an easy way to see what is consuming the most memory?**

For example:

*-Objects / Object data*

*-Textures*

*-Lighting*

*-Particle Systems*

*-Material duplicates*

*-Caches*

*-Anything else that can cause unnecessary memory consumption...*

I'm trying to cut down on memory consumption in a very large scene that would otherwise take ages to do manually.

Comment: Perhaps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/troubleshooting-blenders-memory-use-memory-statistics

Comment: @JamesThomas This doesn't seem to do anything. Broken feature?

Comment: It works for me.  Start it in the command line ("cmd" in windows) navigate to Blender's folder. perhaps "cd \Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\" then "blender --debug-memory" then in Blender, open the file you want to test.  Then open the spacebar menu, run "Memory Statistics" and change the window back to the console to see the detailed memory statistics.  If you have problems, try googling some, and if you still have issues, detail what you did and see here so we can help.

Comment: http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/20-tips-use-google-search-efficiently.html In case this helps.  I knew almost nothing about this till I searched.