# Why does Blender use so much RAM for a mesh?

Tags: memory-management

I'm noticing when loading a 250mb OBJ file (high resolution mesh), Blender goes from 89mb RAM to around 2.1gb. Loading the same mesh in Preview.app uses around 300mb.

**Why is that? Is there a way to reduce usage?**

I suspect this is due to Blender using a half-edge (or similar) data structure for loaded meshes. But even so, I'm surprised by the memory usage, given OBJ is a very inefficient text-based format.

**Update:** following the steps [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/troubleshooting-blenders-memory-use-memory-statistics?rq=1), I printed out memory usage details:

`total memory len: 1077.328 MB
peak memory len: 1077.372 MB
slop memory len: 15.404 MB
 ITEMS TOTAL-MiB AVERAGE-KiB TYPE
 13547 ( 422.624    31.946) Chunk buffer
     1 ( 158.249  162047.156) CDMLoop
     1 ( 118.687  121535.367) CDMEdge
     2 ( 105.500  54015.812) DM_ensure_looptri_data
     2 (  79.125  40511.824) face_nors
     1 (  79.125  81023.578) CDMPoly
     1 (  65.937  67519.648) CDMVert
     2 (  26.375  13503.941) GPUBufferMaterial.polys
     2 (  13.187  6751.980) GPUDrawObject.vert_points`

I'm guessing CDMLoop and CDMEdge are part of the mesh data structure, though I'm not sure what Chunk buffers are. Googling and searching the blender repo on github didn't lead to clear results.